# Garbage value undetected in debug mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I've recently discovered the following in my code:

```
for (NSInteger i; i<x; i++){
...
}
```

Now, clearly, `i` should have been initialised. What I find strange is that while in "debug" profile (XCode), this error goes undetected and the `for` loop executes without issue. When the application is released using the "release" profile, a crash occurs.

What flags are responsible for letting this kind of mistake execute in "debug" profile?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the C language, using an initialized variable isn't an error but an Undefined Behavior.

Undefined behavior exists because C is designed to be a very efficient low-level language. Using an initialized variable is undefined behavior because it allows the compiler to optimize the variable allocation, as no default value is required.

But the compiler is licensed to do whatever he wants when an undefined behavior occurs. The C Standard FAQ says:

> Anything at all can happen; the Standard imposes no requirements. The program may fail to compile, or it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.

So any implementation of an undefined behavior is valid (even if it produces code that formats your hard drive).

Xcode uses different optizations for Debug and Release configurations. Debug configuration has no optimization (`-O0` flag) so the compiled executable must stays close to your code, allowing you to debug it more easily. On the other hand, Release configuration produces strongly optimized executables (`-Os` flag) because you want your application to run fast.

Due to that difference, undefined behaviours may (or may not) produce different results in Release and Debug configurations.

Though the LLVM compiler is quite verbose, it does not emit warnings by default for undefined behaviors. You may however run the static analyzer, which can detect that kind of issues.

More information about undefined behaviors and how they are handled by compilers in [What Every Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

Comment: Many thanks for this, Nicolas. The link that you provided will be quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

This could be considered a [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug). A declaration without an initialization will typically allocate some space in the stack frame for the variable and if you read the variable you will get whatever happened to be at that location in memory. When compiled for the debug profile the storage for variables can shift around compared to release. It just happens that whatever is in that location in memory for debug mode does not cause a crash (probably a positive number) but when in release mode it is some value that causes a crash (probably a negative number).

Answer (score 2):

The clang static analyser should detect this.  I have the analyse when building option switched on always.

Comment: I hadn't actually had the analyse option on, but when I did a separate "Analyse" activity it was flagged up.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is so much flags as the compiler is optimizing out the "unused" variable i.  Release mode includes far more optimizations then debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Different compiler optimizations may or may not use a different memory location or register for you uninitialized variable.  Different garbage (perhaps from previously used variables, computations or addresses used by your app) will be left in these different locations before you start using the variable.

The "responsibility" goes to not initializing the variable, as what garbage is left in what locations may not be visible to the compiler, especially in debug mode with most optimatizations off (e.g. you got "lucky" with the debug build).

Answer (score -1):

i has not been initialized . You are just declaring the i variable not initializing the variable.
Writing just NSInteger i; just declares a variable not initializes it.
You can initialize the variable by below mentioned code.

```
for (NSInteger i=1; i<x; i++){
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the answer to my question.